# How to add a background Image to a whole page in VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js

I tried to add a Background Image that I downloaded to the Home Page of my VueJS application. But when the page gets rendered only a part of the page is covered with the image. I want to fill the whole page with an Image except for the Navbar.

This is my HomeView.vue code:

```
<template>
<div id="Home">
    <h1 class="header"> Welcome {{name}} </h1>
        <h2>A very warm welcome to v2 of QuantifiedSelf</h2>
  </div>      
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';


export default {
Name: 'HomeView',
mounted() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')
    .then((resp ) => console.log(resp.data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.response))
},
data() {
    return {
        name: localStorage.name,
    }
},
};

</script>

<style>
.header{
    margin-top: 80px;
}
#Home{
    background-image: url("../Pics/pic1.jpeg");
    margin-bottom: 250px;
}

</style>
```

And this is the Home page:
[image]

How to fill the page with that image?

Comment: Hello there. You'd probably need to show some HTML/CSS so we can better tell whats going on with the rendering of that block.

Comment: It's just a case of setting some CSS. You probably want to use flexbox, remove padding / margin from body, then on the `#Home` element set `width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: flex;`.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
#home {
   min-height: 100vh
   /*...*/
}
```